# What is the actual meaning of this expression `n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getchar_unlocked();`?

Tags: c, performance, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

In many solutions on codechef for faster input output I came across this expression but I am unable to understand it as I do not have a lot of experience.

```
inline int scan( ) {

int n=0;

int ch=getchar_unlocked();

while( ch <48 )ch=getchar_unlocked();

while( ch >47 )

n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getchar_unlocked();

return n;

}
```

In the above function what is the purpose of the below mentioned expression?

```
n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getchar_unlocked();
```

and what is the meaning of `(n<<3)+(n<<1)`?

Comment: everybody is answering the trivial part with the << but what about the "," part in this line is it a syntactic error?

Comment: The lesson here is not to use codechef to find good code.

Comment: @callmecarrot -- The "," is a comma operator. From K&R: "A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right, and the value of the left expression is discarded. The type and value of the result are the type and value of the right operand."  Basically, they used a comma operator to avoid putting curly braces around the body of the while loop. I have to agree with OliverCharlesworth, if you're looking for good code, avoid codechef.

Comment: @userWithVeryHighNumber, wow thanks for that explanation. starting with c programming around 1985. i must have overlooked this language gem,which i would have completely missed in my long carrier if it was notfor codechef:)

Comment: You didn't miss much :)

Comment: Thank You for all the answers but as i saw @R wrote that this was an old optimization technique so which expression is recommended [n<<3 + n<<1 ] or [ n*10 ]

Comment: You should just write `n*10`. The compiler will output the assembly for `n=(n<<3)+(n<<1)` if that's best for the target processor. (Even compilers from 20 years ago were doing this.)

Comment: Also many of you seems to oppose to be dependent on codechef for good codes. So where can i find good codes to grow in programming field.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input stream consists of characters 0-9, then the code block

```
while( ch >47 )
  n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getchar_unlocked();
```

computes the decimal integral number from the string as long as `ch < 58`, which is `'9'`. If `ch >= 58`, the result is non-sensical.

Let's say the first character when entering the loop is `8`. Then,

```
  n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0' = 8
```

Let's say the second character is `5`. Then,

```
  n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0' = 85
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is shift left operator, that's easy to find in any C tutorials. Just google for C operator list and see.

```
(n << 3) + (n << 1) = n*8 + n*2 = n*10
```

That's an old optimization trick but probably won't be as effective as before in modern architectures with fast multipliers

Comment: It's a mostly-useless optimization; a good compiler will make the same transformation (or an even better one) if it's actually beneficial for the machine you're targetting.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator separates two expressions. The first is evaluated and then discarded, and the second is then evaluated (and this value can be used). The comma operator has lower precedence than assignment, so the interpretation is as the others have said

```
n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getchar_unlocked();
```

multiply n by 10, add the value of ch's offset from 0, and store the result in n. Then call `getchar_unlocked()` and assign the return value to ch. The comma isn't doing anything but adding confusion to the code here. It would be better to use two statements.

I've never seen the comma operator used outside of loop initialization/increment, but it is handy there.

```
for (count = 0, index = 1; index < MAX_INDEX; count += 1, index += 2) {
    /* some code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`n<<3` means `n` is shifted 3 bit to the left and `n<<1` means `n` is shifted 1 bit to the left and then the the ASCII value of `0` is subtracted from `ch` to get the actual number in `int`.

Example: when `n=2` and `n` is 1 bit shifted to left it becomes `4`.
Because the binary representation of `2` is `010` and when it shifts 1 bit to left it becomes `100` which is the binary representation of `4`. It works in the same way  for `n<<3`.

Comment: i was thinking to write the same answer but then i have spotted the "," in this line .. so i am not so sure anymore is it a syntactic error?